# Converting nested loops into LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a property that has a `DateTime` and an array of DateTimes.

```
 public DateTime date { get; set; }
 public DateTime[] dateArray { get; set; }
```

Currently I am using nested loops to get my values, but I am trying to change this to LINQ and cannot get it correct.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < allPropertyValues.Count(); i ++)
 {
      var list = new List<DateTime>();
      for (var j = 0; j < allPropertyValues[i].dateArray.Count(); j++)
      {
           if (allPropertyValues[i].dateArray[j]
                 >= allPropertyValues[i].date)
                list.Add(allPropertyValues[i].dateArray);
      }
 }
```

The `allPropertyValues` variable is currently an array of static properties, and in each index, there is one `date` value and multiple `dateArray` values. How do I iterate through each property result and compare each date, with the multiple values of the `dateArray` that I get, using LINQ? Thanks very much in advance.

Also, how would I do a compare of the two instances, as it doesn't appear that I can use `>` or `<` in a LINQ expression. I haven't used LINQ too much but am trying to figure it out properly, thanks again.

Comment: The line `list.Add(allPropertyValues[i].dateArray);`  shouldn't be `list.AddRange(allPropertyValues[i].dateArray)`?

Comment: You didn't clearly state what you want to do in order for us to understand the code you used, so please read [ask].

Comment: Felipe is right; this code is nonsensical. Either you meant to add all the dates in the array, or, more likely, you meant to add dateArray[j].  Which is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these guidelines:

- Work your way from inside to outside
- Extract common subexpressions into something simpler
- Ask yourself what the *concept* is that the loop represents, rather than what the loop *does*.  Then write a query that represents that concept.

OK.  We have our inner loop, which is a mess. I've fixed the obvious error mentioned in a comment.

```
  for (var j = 0; j < allPropertyValues[i].dateArray.Count(); j++)
  {
    if (allPropertyValues[i].dateArray[j] >= allPropertyValues[i].date)
      list.Add(allPropertyValues[i].dateArray[j]);
  }
```

Why it is a mess?  Well, we have a common subexpression all over the show here.  Simplify it.

```
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < v.dateArray.Count(); j++)
  {
    if (v.dateArray[j] >= v.date)
      list.Add(v.dateArray[j]);
  }
```

Already this is one million times easier to read. Can we make it even easier? Yes. We have a second common subexpression:

```
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < v.dateArray.Count(); j++)
  {
    DateTime d = v.dateArray[j];
    if (d >= v.date)
      list.Add(d);
  }
```

And now we realize that `j` is unnecessary:

```
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  foreach (DateTime d in v.dateArray)
  {
    if (d >= v.date)
      list.Add(d);
  }
```

OMG so much easier to understand. Now it becomes clear what the meaning of the code is, and so we can much more easily turn it into a query:

```
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  list.AddRange(from d in v.dateArray where d >= v.date select d);
```

Or

```
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  list.AddRange(v.dateArray.Where(d => d >= v.date));
```

And now we're down to two lines of extremely clear code.

Now we've rewritten our inner loop.  Put it in the outer loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allPropertyValues.Count(); i++)
{
  var list = new List<DateTime>();
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  list.AddRange(v.dateArray.Where(d => d >= v.date));
}
```

Now again, examine the code. Can it be simplified? Yes. We notice that the list is being created earlier than necessary.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allPropertyValues.Count(); i++)
{
  var v = allPropertyValues[i];
  var list = v.dateArray.Where(d => d >= v.date).ToList();
}
```

Can we make this simpler still? Sure. Now we can notice that `i` is unnecessary:

```
foreach (var v in allPropertyValues)
{
  var list = v.dateArray.Where(d => d >= v.date).ToList();
}
```

And now we've reduced the whole thing to a two-line program fragment.

If what you want is a list of lists then we can go even further:

```
List<List<DateTime>> lists = allPropertyValues
  .Select(v => v.dateArray.Where(d => d >= v.date).ToList())
  .ToList();
```

And we're done.

The takeaway here is: **constantly be asking yourself how you can simplify your program to make it more clear and concise**.  Then apply a series of careful, small, correct refactorings.  Every time you do, ask yourself again: can I now make it even better?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and detailed description.

Comment: @wrikgee: You're welcome. The problem with loops is that they say *what the computer does* when what you want to read and write is *what logical operations am I performing on this data?*  If you can write your loops as queries you'll find that they get easier to understand.

Comment: @EricLippert excellent traverse of code

Answer (score 1):

Try below linq query

```
allPropertyValues.Where(e=> e.dateArray.Any(d=>d>= e.date)).Select(e=>e.dateArray)
```